# TypeScript infer value type based on a passed key

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I am encountering a problem with the typization of a reducer function that aims to update any given property of the userData stored in the slice. It takes an array with the key and a value, where the key should be of type TUserData, and the value - of the specified type for the respective key in TUserData.

Here is the reducer:

```
updateUserProp(state, action: { payload: [keyof TUserData, TUserData[keyof TUserData]]; type: string }) {
    const [key, value] = action.payload;

    state.userData![key] = value;
},
```

And here is the TUserData type

```
type TUserData = {
    email: string;
    uid: string;
    username: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    phoneNumber: string;
    createdOn: string;
    initials?: string;
    status: EUserStatus;
    profilePhoto?: string;
    chats?: { [x: string]: EChatStatus };
    messagesSent?: { [x: string]: boolean };
}
```

The error

> Type 'string | { [x: string]: EChatStatus; } | { [x: string]: boolean;
> } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string & EUserStatus &
> (WritableDraft<{ [x: string]: EChatStatus; }> | undefined) &
> (WritableDraft<{ [x: string]: boolean; }> | undefined)'. Type
> 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string & EUserStatus &
> (WritableDraft<{ [x: string]: EChatStatus; }> | undefined) &
> (WritableDraft<{ [x: string]: boolean; }> | undefined)'.

is from this line of codea state.userData![key] = value;

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIFcwAsDKY6TIDeAUAJDoDO0AIgXAFzIAqAqtVHfsgD7IjoANoIDc5YJXbQAMgHs4AE1ABzJgCNZswRDggxAXxIkIAgLbIAolKh4CVYuQDyAOWkBJZxeQBeZACJZEEFQCD8AGnJUAHVUAE0ffzgAdzgAT3DyACFWHHjfPzUqdIiyRwAxMvdPBICYGGCQUIj9MRN0cwsAYSwCWzB7UjJUTuY3ADUvfMQwYAA3JvIaACVUMuYahSg4GDAMshoLaQtmCxoNiG1IBQyWozBUgAcUNg4uOATBiFM4YEEmSjAUBUYgowAU-0BwPIVGgIDgpggEKBIGUIJgwCgAOc8MRyAByNR5EEcCxOKRULIDywgQgznaamg5JRIIQUB0V0cICZhLIoGAMzggkoAH5uSCAXZKEwrBw%20lQQQ8oLJ0doAArUsCyUV4yHM8gIHpgEVMIjIADaAA9uQBdaXdXr4fqUZC3MgIyiUODKCCUHAmMDa02Wm3qTTaXQugxiEgwdAgBAzQLIdAPBQECDWVVKh4ACnIEsgTAw2D6EBK02AgRN5EpaUE8nB5oA1hBUsqWNY3mEO696GaW22YD3aPRrdaQWR7k8xeR9BEAJQOMgIQIA5ut7uzQXoCDWhIVwIAOgedYb4sdEEPMM49AAhP3W3vfFvBDuDCQgA)

**EDIT**

I resolved the error with this solution

```
function updateUserProp<K extends keyof TUserData>(
    state: { userData?: TUserData },
    action: {
        payload: [K, TUserData[K]];
        type: string;
    },
) {
    const [key, value] = action.payload;
    state.userData![key] = value;
}
```

[Working solution playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/KYOwrgtgBAogqgZ2AJwMoBcCG6wKgbwCgBIAeQDkAZASXJigF4oAiAexABsBLEYZgGhIBBAOpCAmoxaYA7pgCeAkgCE4qSU2YAjXIsFkAYgZp0pbAGbnuvJQF8A3IVCRYAYQAW2DNlwFhrgBVqADV6TUwAY3QuADc%20fQARACUhAwCzABNkTHN0JWIEmEoYAJgEzOAOYHRgDLtHQnR5AAdgKADEFATsTCkiYmAITC4OAC4oBHRkHgBzR2IwLgzxyemQOZJcFBBMCGAVqdn58y5kSfJd-YnD9fmOTHPLg7WN4mb3dmBySC0UZ6OSBFkMBsLVSCB-rcSDwuNFMBwEAB%20SGvSY%20BDjeBINBYHAIebNZCsE5VAAKH3QrGR1xe8winnQSPG%20CgAG0AB4ogC6mI8XlxvgcJD2CAQmBmwAQqFA6GpLI53PGWlYrCqmBAUCFQsI5jAICiXHYUDAzQyoM6yFJROaAB4ANJQYDsmogDJ4ADWwHkxPaFu6WAAfAAKEhomrM43Y-2YakdKM9TX6SLRdjMkhvBQcViYZZsu38X3xrCsu1crnzWyCACUfmIEXYkzZnvkBZi8LAwC5UmThpAADpmpnsxl5mHgH2tshowBCVnNrtMNscDuOWyEQgms01C1W1jNIP4SsEKCD%20RZnPjVnMMO4ASwC3ePF9igmGBc2xVwhAA)

The function works fine on its own. But when used as a reducer, it allows a value of different type (as long as it's among the valid types for the entire object) to be assigned to the key.

`dispatch(authActions.updateUserProp(["status", undefined]))` doesn't produce an error, but `updateUserProp({}, { payload: ["status", undefined]})` (ran from the playground) does.

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, with all necessary types, without fragments of code. One good way to make sure you've included everything necessary is to do it in [the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and make sure it **only** has the error you're asking about, not unrelated ones. (Then you can put that code in the question, and also include a link to the playground. [[See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386543/) for a note about an SO bug and workaround re posting the link.)

Comment: What is "`dispatch`"? Are you using some sort of third-party library aside from TypeScript where you're having a problem? Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the actual problem you're having when we paste it into our own IDEs. If the playground is good but your project/IDE is not, then you need to investigate the difference between those and [edit] the question with a [mre]. Otherwise it's very hard to know how to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) constrained by `keyof TUserData` so that the compiler can infer the specific key as shown below:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAogqgZwgJwMrAIbAK4KgXimwDsBrYgewHdiBuAKFElgGEALLdLXAosymg0bhoAFUQoAIlgy8A3vQCQEALYYAlgBsAXFATBk64gHMGi7OoAmu-YZNncKYhhUQbBo6aUAzdcn0Aci5ueh72SpoYgcHudl6KYGwUxBAB2CoARiixnmYAxsgQWBCWAPLEOeGKRurA6hiaCAD8lfH63Ai68EhomDgIZmDIFL6aEAAKScAULaFx+RzAzbpyUADaAB6tALpd7Jx9PAC+Zq4ICBjGEAioEMTAs6ubO7oZFBRjGMRQJ-S-9N4SHk6skiGBLMUJMhxsMwAAeADSUAgG2Ad0seFIEBAIyg4h60kwAD4ABRKdpolZEAkyWb4qQyH4AGiUGGB6mSKyUCQwIE0FAw1nWCKZeKhhIwawR222ZkUTBCtlySiOLIAlFAFIo8sl9OssSBRQA3BrYCDbXhskHEAB0YF5-MFZgpEBtjmQEoAhGsDRbCCbNGaGEd6EA)

```ts
function updateUserProp<K extends keyof TUserData>(
  state: { userData?: TUserData },
  action: {
    payload: [K, TUserData[K]];
    type: string;
  },
) {
  const [key, value] = action.payload;
  state.userData![key] = value;
}
```

Comment: This eliminated the error, but it doesn't type guard if I pass an incorrectly typed value for a given key. As long as the value is string | { [x: string]: EChatStatus; } | { [x: string]: boolean; } | undefined it accepts it as valid, even if it doesn't correspond to the particular key

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78087482/typescript-infer-value-type-based-on-a-passed-key/78087523?noredirect=1#comment137663987_78087523) @kokiqn Please provide a [mre] demonstrating the described problem. You can use the playground link in my answer as a starting template if you’d like.

Comment: My guess is that this is going to turn into [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) and want a distributive object type as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/W4a7Aw). But yeah, without a [mre] in the question it's just speculation.

Comment: @jsejcksn It works fine when I replicate it in the playground. It appears it is a redux-related issue, as the problem occurs only with the reducer function being dispatched.